# Android is there any way to only rotate one component were other component in same layout will not rotate

Tags: java, android

I want the content of `webview` vertical to horizontal as device rotate, but not the other components. 
I mean button below the webview should not rotate,

So i am trying to rotate the content of `webview` vertical to horizontal or vice versa but cant do it .

Is there any way to only rotate one component were other component in same layout will not rotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use system to do that for you, the answer is "no".